# Unwanted labels on bar plot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get zero's on all my bars, despite trying to remove them by setting yerr=None, I'm still getting the same issue. The bars otherwise plot correctly. How can I remove the 0 that I get printed above each bar.

```
N = len(my_tuple)
plt.figure(0)
ind = np.arange(N)  
width = 0.35       
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, g_tuple, width, color='r',  linewidth=2,alpha=0.8)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, f_tuple, width, color='y', linewidth=2,alpha=0.8)
ax.set_ylabel('XXX')
ax.set_title('XXX')
ax.set_xticks(ind+width)
ax.set_xticklabels( lob_tuple )
ax.legend( (rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('G', 'F') )
autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)
```

I've tried `yerr=None`, `yerr=0`, but this doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out its the `autolabel` command that does this whilst I was looking within the bar method.